# textarea - disable resize on x or y?

Tags: css, resize, textarea

I know it's possible to disable the resize of a `textarea` by using:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

But is it possible to disable either x or y? instead of both

Answer (score 282):

```
resize: vertical;
```

or

```
resize: horizontal;
```

Quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLrh7Lte/

Answer (score 44):

Sure it is possible with css and jquery

**CSS:**

```
resize: vertical;
resize: horizontal;
```

**jQuery**

```
$('textarea').css("resize", "vertical");
$('textarea').css("resize", "horizontal");
```

**Bootstrap**
just put the class in Textarea

for the vertical resize: `vresize`

for the horizontal resize: `hresize`

Comment: Both the CSS and the jQuery solutions do the same thing, so you can pick which one works best for your situation. I mention it in case someone interprets that you have to use both.

Answer (score 10):

You must use *horizontal* or *vertical* values for property.

```
resize: vertical;
```

or

```
resize: horizontal;
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp