# How do you allow a user to manually resize a <div> element vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, slider

I have 2 div elements inside another div, and they are displayed as a block each. So *div1* ends up right above *div2*.

I want to add a "bar" of some kind that the user can click and drag which will end up resizing *div2*, and *div1* will be automatically resized by the same amount.

The parent of *div1* and *div2* has style: `display:flex;flex-direction:column;` and *div1* has `flex-grow:1` so it automatically resizes.

I want the resize bar to be something like this:

[image: resize Bar]

How do I add something like this? Also is there any way I can change the look of it in CSS?

Comment: possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559527/ (this is for *row*, you can adapt it for *column flexbox*) do you want a demo?

Comment: What element is used for the text input? If you have a textarea see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567707/textarea-disable-resize-on-x-or-y)

Comment: @T04435 div2 has a text area but other elements as well, so i'd like to make it so only div2 gets resized.

Comment: @kukkuz i saw the code snippet there, and that's what I want, but is there a way to do this simply and without using JS? And how i can change the look of the bar

Comment: with CSS you have just the option to use [**`resize`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: @kukkuz ok so the only solution would be to create another div in between div1 and div2 which will be the slider, (and i can add all the CSS i want to style it)?. Unfortunately I don't get the JS code. can I have that demo you offered? you can paste it as an answer so it's clear

Comment: yeah sure, give me a moment...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your *column flexbox* you can use [**`resize`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) on one of the divs and adjust the other automatically using `flex-grow` set to one - the ***downside*** is that the *slider* is not very customizeable:

- add `resize: vertical` to one of the flex items
- add `flex: 1` to the other flex item (so that *this* flex item will adjust automatically in response to the changing height of the other flex item as it is resized)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  height: 50%;
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
  resize: vertical; /* resize vertical */
  overflow: auto; /* resize works for overflow other than visible */
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1; /* adjust automatically */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="block block-1">
    Block 1
  </div>
  <div class="block block-2">
    Block 2
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution

Instead you can use a `mousedown` listener that *registers* a `mousemove` listener that updates the `block-1` height (and *reset* the `mouseup` event) - see demo below:

```js
let block = document.querySelector(".block-1"),
  slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

// on mouse down (drag start)
slider.onmousedown = function dragMouseDown(e) {
  // get position of mouse
  let dragX = e.clientY;
  // register a mouse move listener if mouse is down
  document.onmousemove = function onMouseMove(e) {
    // e.clientY will be the position of the mouse as it has moved a bit now
    // offsetHeight is the height of the block-1
    block.style.height = block.offsetHeight + e.clientY - dragX + "px";
    // update variable - till this pos, mouse movement has been handled
    dragX = e.clientY;
  }
  // remove mouse-move listener on mouse-up (drag is finished now)
  document.onmouseup = () => document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  height: 50%;
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
  resize: vertical; /* resize vertical */
  overflow: auto; /* resize works for overflow other than visible */
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1; /* adjust automatically */
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow on small width */
}

.slider {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  cursor: row-resize;
  user-select: none; /* disable selection */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="block block-1">
    Block 1
  </div>
  <div class="slider">slider</div>
  <div class="block block-2">
    Block 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for thanks! I messed up somewhere though. For the querySelector part I put the parameters as "#id_of_first_block" and ".class_of_slider". I pasted the JS code within `<script>` tag, above both div elements. Made sure to put `display:flex` in the container element and `flex-grow:1` in the 2nd block to make it resize automatically, as well as `resize:vertical` in the 2nd block.

Comment: for some reason it isn't doing anything. when i hover over, the vertical adjust icon appears. When I click and drag up and down nothing happens. i know i messed up somewhere cause your code snippet runs just fine

Comment: @AndrewKor  Can you give me a codepen or fiddle, let me have a look

Comment: first of all some pointers: 

1) multiple class declaration for slider element
2) don't use script tag between element - better to keep it at the end

Comment: so you can do this:  1) specify a height for your column flexbox - otherwise flex-grow has no meaning
2) you are setting height for the bottom element - so a sign-reverse here: `block.style.height = block.clientHeight - (e.clientY - dragX) + "px"`

Comment: @AndrewKor see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eodVPN (as you have `min-height` set, you can resize within those limits - try removing the `min-height`s too)

Comment: @AndrewKor Let me know if you have any doubts, thanks!

Comment: Works beautifully now :). How do I prevent overflow when i click and drag "past the end" of either div? (For example if the min height is 300 and i want to go to 250, it will stop at 300 but there will be overflow on the `<body>` for some reason) -- even without minheight, going to -50/same thing). Also i'm not sure what you meant with the min-height part. I want those two divs to absolutely have a minimum height for when the window resizes and also when they click and drag the slider too far. It's still ok to leave min-height there? i don't currently see any issues using min-height

Comment: @AndrewKor having `min-height` is okay... regarding overflow I can't see any overflow in the codepen link...

Comment: I had trouble getting a similar setup working (`div`s would be fixed, and dragging the resize handle did nothing). After I removed the flex property on `div` 1 (I tried 0 and 1 as values for `flex`), I was able to use the handle...

Comment: Some time ago i used this method successfully. The only downside was that the flex elements did not start with same width (i used horisontal scrollig), and to solve this, i used CSS:  width: 33vw; 33-because i  had 3 elements. What is your this opinion about this approach?