# Edit script for resizable div

Tags: javascript

I found this script for resizing divs vertically.
[How do you allow a user to manually resize a <div> element vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565001/how-do-you-allow-a-user-to-manually-resize-a-div-element-vertically#55565128)

I was able to use it, but now I need to modify it to make sure to resize another div horizontally.
I tried to modify it but the results are not what I wanted, some traits don't work well.

For example:

```
let blockH = document.querySelector("#div1"),
  sliderH = document.querySelector(".sliderH");

sliderH.onmousedown = function dragMouseDown(e) {
    let dragX = e.clientX;
  document.onmousemove = function onMouseMove(e) {
    blockH.style.width = blockH.offsetWidth + dragX + "px";
    dragX = e.clientX;
}

document.onmouseup = () => document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" id="div1">
    Block 1
  </div>
  <div class="sliderH"></div>
  <div class="block" id="div2">
    Block 2
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#div2{
     flex: 1; 

}

#div1{
  resize: horizontal; 
  overflow: auto; 
}

.sliderH {
   cursor: col-resize;
   user-select: none; 
   width: 10px;
 }
  .container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   width: 100%;
   }
```

---

But don't work very good.

Someone can help me to edit the script for horizontally resizing?
Thank you